# Cannot get my Spring Batch to run any other job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch application using an h2 database. When the job ran the very first time, it threw an exception. Now every time I run any other job it fails with the first exception and does not run the new files I dropped in the processing folder. I am unable to run any other job because the information has been persisted in the Job repository. How can I reset what's there so I can run other jobs? I need to clear the job metadata from the H2 database that is in my classpath but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What exception are you facing?  How are you running the job?

Comment: I got an exception the first time as I wasn't catching the 400 bad request from the last step in the tasks.  I fixed the exception but running the job stills runs the old data. Even the data I send has changed i.e. the resource I was posting to the Rest service. However, it seems it's been stored in the job repository. I want to get rid of it but the old data